# Proving $x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, logarithms

Can someone give me a tip on how to prove an inequality like this one?

> $$x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x>0$$

While doing some exercises on the differentiation chapter of my analysis book,  I stumbled into some weird inequalities I'm supposed to prove. I couldn't do it. I guess they're not supposed to be complicated (they're one of the first exercises), but still, i'm lost. Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Hence, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-1+x=\frac{x^2}{x+1}>0.$

Thus, $f(x)> f(0)=0$.

Let $g(x)=x-\ln(1+x)$.

Thus, $g'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{x}{x+1}>0$ and

$g(x)>g(0)=0$.

Done!

Answer (score 3):

For $x\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\\
&\le\int_0^x\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=x
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t}\\
&\ge\int_0^x(1-t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=x-\frac{x^2}2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

- For the rightmost inequality,  $\ln$ is concave,  and $y=x$ is the equation of the tangent to the representative curve of $\ln(1+x)$ at $x=0$.
  Remember the representative curve of a concave function is *below* its tangent at any point.
- For the leftmost inequality, you have this corollary of the *Mean Value theorem*:

  > Let $f,g$ be functions differentiable on an interval $I$, $a\in I$. Suppose $f(a)\ge g(a)$ and $f'(x)>g'x)$ for all $x>a$. Then $f(x) >g(x)$ for all $x>a$.

Now the derivative of $\ln(1+x)\;$ is $\;\dfrac1{1+x}$, and we have this high-school identity:
$$\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-\dots +(-1)^nx^n+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}$$

which shows $\;\dfrac 1{1+x}>1-x\;$ for $\;x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x)=x-\ln(1+x)$$ then $$f(0)=0$$ and $$f'(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}>0$$
can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

By MVT, $\exists c_1,c_2\in (0,x) $ :

$$(\ln (1+x)-x)-0=$$
$$x (\frac {1}{1+c_1}-1)=$$
$$\frac {-c_1x}{1+c_1}<0$$

and

$$(\ln (1+x)-x+\frac {x^2}{2})-0=$$
$$x (\frac {1}{1+c_2}-1+c_2) =$$
$$\frac {x c_2^2}{1+c_2}>0$$